How to maven build in offline jenkins server?
(I’m not good at English, so I used a translator. I’m sorry.)
This is an offline Jenkins+JDK+Maven environment.
I am trying to do a Maven build and have installed the necessary plugins manually.
However, the following error occurs when building Maven.
Exception in thread “main” java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:133)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.main(Maven35Main.java:65)
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe {jenkins_dir}/temp/jenkins7436717266301016827.sh
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE

I searched, but the written solution did not solve the problem and the same error occurred.
Can you tell me where I missed it?
(As a side note, This is my first time working with Maven offline.)
thank you.
I'm trying to this:

shutdown and restart jenkins (tomcat)
re-install jenkins.war
check tomcat log:
WARNING [Executor #0 for Built-In Node : executing [project_name] #9] hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.buildEnvironment no revision found corresponding to svn://[IP]:[PORT]/[SOURCE]; known: [svn://IP]/[SOURCE]]


This error message java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) indicates an network issue... so I suppose you are behind a proxy/ firewall etc...

The server you need to configure is an offline server. Is there anything network-related I need to ask the administrator for Maven settings?

I tried many things, but there was no way other than opening to all IPs. If you use Jenkins, please refer to this.
